# Discretized heat equation giving an unobservable system with point measurement

Tags: partial-differential-equations, control-theory, heat-equation

I am trying to discretize the heat equation in 1-D polar coordinates. I have:

$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha\left( \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} +\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial^2r} \right) $ with boundary condition as $-\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\bigg|_{r=l}=\frac{h}{k}T$

Now there are a variety of methods to discretise this and try to handle the singularity at the center using axisymmetry etc. Discretising this only in the spatial domain I have a set of differential equations that give me the state space $\dot{x}=Ax$. Where $x_{i}$ is the temperature at the $i^{th} $discretized point that I have chosen.

Next, I am trying to measure the temperature at the left most point in this 1-D system. Hence I have the corresponding $C$ matrix in $y=Cx$

My problem is that if I increase the number of discretization points the system starts becoming unobservable. Physically the system should be observable and stays so for low values of discretization points.

What's going on here? Does some mathematical theorem exist that limits the number of discretization points?

Comment: What do you mean by "system becomes unobservable"?

Comment: I mean that the observability matrix (for (C,A)) does not have rank=n (which is the number of states, which is again equal to the number of discretised points that I have chosen in 1-D)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't familiar with the concept. In that case, maybe numerical rounding 
errors are the reason for the loss of observability when you increase the number of points. I can't be sure, but my advice would be to either use a more sophisticated finite difference scheme, or use a global basis, Bessel functions for example

Comment: I would also think it is probably due to numerical reasons. For example for large $A$ in observable or controllable canonical form the condition number of $A$ if often bad. So maybe a more balanced state representation might yield better results.

Comment: @ YuriyS, @KwinvanderVeen. Yes, earlier even I thought that numerical issues might make the system unobservable but the system is becoming unobservable for very small values of number of states, after around 20 states (number of discretised points), the system starts becoming unobservable. Surely this is not due to numerical errors as MATLAB can handle large values, also the values in the matrix A and C are not very large (very small) so as to make the matrix ill conditioned. Anyways, thanks for the replies.

Comment: What are the values of the largest and smallest singular value of the observability matrix?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen It's large, around 10^14, and very small around 10^-10 . Do you think this is a problem? Can you suggest any other method?